# Block subscribers completely from beckend on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, web-applications

I am designing my website on wordpres. And I want to bolck subscribers completely from backend. I managed little little with some plugins. But the problem is that when they post something they get their display name beside their post and when they click on their display name they got redirected to their profile page on the backend. Please help me how to redirect subscriber to custom profile page when they click on their dispaly name and completely block them from beckend.

Comment: I think this plugin will help you: [Remove Dashboard Access](http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/). It has an option to redirect users to a URL you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great plugin by Christopher Davies (chrisguitarguy) which does what you are asking:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: No Dashboard
Description: Don't allow subscribers to access to the wp-dashboard
Author: Christopher Davis
Plugin URI: https://gist.github.com/chrisguitarguy/1877504
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse43054_activation' );
function wpse43054_activation()
{
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    if( $role ) $role->remove_cap( 'read' );
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse43054_deactivation' );
function wpse43054_deactivation()
{
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    if( $role ) $role->add_cap( 'read' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse43054_maybe_redirect' );
function wpse43054_maybe_redirect()
{
    if( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'read' ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
        exit();
    }
}

add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'wpse43054_hijack_admin_bar', 10, 3 );
function wpse43054_hijack_admin_bar( $null, $user_id, $key )
{
    if( 'show_admin_bar_front' != $key ) return null;
    if( ! current_user_can( 'read' ) ) return 0;
    return null;
}
```